# Use Regular Expression get word have defined characters and bold style in IOS

Tags: ios, regex

I need to get a word in sentence input and bold it's style.
This is my code

```
NSString *regexString = @"(\\<-\\w+(\\s\\w+)*\\->)\\s";

NSString *aString = @"Notes on iOS7 going to take a <-lot-> of getting used to!";

NSRegularExpression *regex1 = [NSRegularExpression
                              regularExpressionWithPattern:regexString
                              options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                              error:&error];

NSString *match =
[aString substringWithRange:[regex1 rangeOfFirstMatchInString:aString
                                                     options:NSMatchingCompleted range:NSMakeRange(0, [aString length])]];

NSLog(@"Matched string: %@", match);
```

String : Notes on iOS7 going to take a <-lot-> of getting used to!

String printed in NSLog: Matched string: <-lot->

In this I just need to get "lot" word

Expected printed: Matched string: lot

I also need to change type of this word in the sentence like this: Notes on iOS7 going to take a **lot** of getting used to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is sample code to print that word:

```
NSError *error = NULL;
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?<=<-)\\w+(?=->)" options:0 error:&error];
if (regex) {
    NSRange rangeOfFirstMatch = [regex rangeOfFirstMatchInString:subject options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [subject length])];
    if (!NSEqualRanges(rangeOfFirstMatch, NSMakeRange(NSNotFound, 0))) {
        NSString *result = [string substringWithRange:rangeOfFirstMatch];
    } else {
        // Match attempt failed
    }
} else {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

**Explanation**

- The lookbehind `(?<=<-)` asserts that what precedes is `<-` (but doesn't match it)
- `\w+` matches word chars
- The lookahead `(?=->)` asserts that what follows is `->` (but doesn't match it)

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Comment: Tks for ur help. But it still get <-lot-> word. The need that "lot" word would be better. Best regard.

Comment: Sorry, I had misunderstood. Please see the updated code, it will match `lot` by itself. Also in the process of adding explanation. :)

Comment: Wow. So cool. Tks for ur help. I will vote up when have enough reputation.

Comment: Thanks for the green checkmark. :) Happy to help you with bold, but not sure what you want. You want to replace `lot` with `<b>lot</b>`?

Comment: I have some issues that when have lots of word in <- -> such as <-lots of a-> it not display "lots of a". About bold I mean that on IOS I need to display it in label like: "Notes on iOS7 going to take a **lot** of getting used to!"

Comment: For the first one (not just a word, but a sentence in the tag), change the regex to `@"(?<=<-).*?(?=->)"` For the second one, you need to tell me what tag you need around the word to make it bold as I don't code in this system. Is it `<b>`? Then I make a regex replacement. For instance I can replace `<-lot->` with `<b>lot</b>`, would that work?

Comment: No this is core code in IOS. It must be handle in Xcode.

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea. I was drawn to the question by the regex tag, that's my specialty. :) I recommend you ask a second question just about producing bold text as more people will look at it (questions fall off the list very quickly)

Comment: Sorry nvtien, what do you mean by `thanks in advance?` Worried that my last comment wasn't clear. :) Hope to help you again with regex sometime.